# On which Cassandra nodes will hints get generated?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to experiment with some of the settings related to hint files for my cluster.
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/hints.html

My cluster configuration is pretty simple.
Quorum setting: LOCAL_QUORUM
Replication Factor : 3
Durable writes: true

Number of nodes : 3

Data center : 1

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.107.233.76   38.68 MiB  256          100.0%            9c707e0b-60e1-4e7a-9af9-a8dd9fcec47f  RAC3
UN  10.103.72.48    37.78 MiB  256          100.0%            26698603-038a-4a6f-91da-305ae8fdd5aa  RAC2
UN  10.103.109.192  38.95 MiB  256          100.0%            82adeeca-8284-4011-af60-6cff83d365f0  RAC1
```

Keyspace and table info:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cycling
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
   'replication_factor' : 3 
  } AND durable_writes = true;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cycling.race_winners;


CREATE TABLE cycling.race_winners (
  fullname text, 
  race_name text,
  race_position int,
  some_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (race_name, race_position));
```

Took a node down and performed a series of inserts and deletes.
Looked at the hints file generated at two nodes inside
/opt/cassandra/data/hints

I don't see anything related to my keypsace or table.

I have checked the cassandra.yaml and the hint file directory is correct.
Will the hint file be generated on one node or both nodes? I did the inserts and deletes through one session.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinator of a write request (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) by definition is responsible for coordinating the:

1. sending of the mutation to all replicas,
2. waiting for acknowledgement from the replicas,
3. the configured consistency level (CL) is met, and
4. if the CL is achieved, store a hint for replicas which did not respond.

To answer your question, the hint will only be stored on one node (the coordinator). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, @Erick. I just don't see the files on any hint files on the other two nodes.